# What is the function of 'en' in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

> Sa présentation en permet une lecture facile.

This sentence was presented to me and I couldn't figure out why 'en' is supposed to be employed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most literal rendering in English would be "of that/it" or "of X" (but placed at the end of the sentence). Often, though, it isn't translated directly. It is completely different from "en" meaning "in", so don't let that throw you off. On an interesting side note, Italian has a word used almost exactly the same way ("ne").

Comment: Welcome to the site! As a general rule, translation is a poor substitute for grammatical analysis, it eschews the source language constructs, substituting expression equivalents which provide no insight whatsoever about the language... i.e. here the learner doesn't know that this isn't a preposition, they may not even notice from knowing it's translated to "of it" etc. and therefore makes this a missed opportunity to learn about the French language, which is the topic...

Answer (score 2):

*En* est un pronom qui fait référence à ce dont la lecture est facilitée par la présentation en question, un livre, une affiche, une notice, etc.

*En* is a pronoun that refers to the writing material which has its readability improved thanks to the presentation the sentence is about, whether a book, a poster, or whatever document.

Without *en*, the sentence might have been:

> La présentation aérée permet une lecture facile du document.

Comment: @Jardin Un pronom !

Answer (score 1):

**1. With *"en"* pronoun**

> Sa présentation en permet une lecture facile.

The above sentence could be translated by:

> Its presentation makes it easy to read

**2. Without *"en"* pronoun**

> Sa présentation permet une lecture facile.

The above sentence could be translated by:

> Its presentation allows easy reading